# Browser autofill issue in safari

Tags: html, safari, autofill

I'am working on a payment form design. I need to put `credit card number` & its `expiry date` fields as autofill. `Chrome` browser working perfectly while `Safari` doesn't (`Safari doesn't recognize the expiry_date field to be autofill`).

Here are my two fields.

```
<input type="text" id="card_number" />
<input type="text" id="expiry_date" placeholder="MM / YY" />
```

There may be solutions by separating `month and year of the expiry date`, but i should do it as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.

The problem is that when entering the credit card validity date in safari, it is entered as "MM . YYYY" instead of "MM / YYYY".

Input's `value.replace('.', '/');` when I did it solved the problem for me.

```
function setExpDate() {
    var expDateInput = document.querySelector('#expiry_date');
    expDateInput.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

    function updateValue() {
        expDateInput.value = expDateInput.value.replace('.', '/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/

Look into [Autofill detail tokens](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill):

Form fields can be specified to be considered for autofill of the credit card expiry date [in two ways](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-cc-exp):

- `cc-exp`, for a date in YYYY-MM form, or
- `cc-exp-year` and `cc-exp-month` for individual fields holding YYYY and MM, respectively.